# Prevent a web application from making HTTP requests outside a domain whitelist

Tags: javascript, html, npm, websecurity

I envision a useful security feature for browsers/web-clients, but I haven't been able to find any resources or discussion on the topic, so I would like an answer to evaluate whether such a feature could/should/does exist.

**Question**: Is it possible to restrict which domains a web client is able to make HTTP requests to, based on a whitelist of allowable domains?

**Justification:**

Front-end web developers tend to use third party libraries. It's easier, faster, more maintainable, and often contributes to a higher quality product. Many of these libraries are open-source and reputable, but it's very difficult to audit all third party dependencies, and using them implies some risk assessment and a level of reasonable trust. It is conceivable that an external library could contain malicious code.

As an example, suppose I am developing an application that accepts credit card details. Throughout the app, I am using a third party UI/styling framework. Without my knowledge, it turns out that the third party library contained malicious JavaScript designed to steal credit card numbers and POST them to an external site. This seems like a common-pattern of malicious code in web apps, because in order to do some malicious effect outside the web application, an action must be performed against some external resource (either the app domain server, or an evil third party server).

In this example, if it was possible to immutably whitelist the app domain (such that that a third party site couldn't be whitelisted later by the malicious code), than it would be impossible for malicious code to steal the credit card numbers by sending them to a third-party site. As a browser security feature, this might look like (1) an HTML attribute that is loaded before any JavaScript, (2) a JavaScript interface that allows defining a whitelist, but doesn't permit later defining a less restrictive whitelist.

Obviously this doesn't protect against all evil acts malicious code might take, but it does eliminate a large area of concern. Most evil (but usefully worthwhile) actions would require a network request (stealing sensitive data, sending off mined bitcoins, unwanted analytics, etc.). The truth is, the front-end dependencies I include might be making external HTTP requests and I might not know.

Does a scheme like this already exist? Would this kind of feature be helpful or problematic?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-Security-Policy?

Comment: CSP `connect-src` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#directive-connect-src

Comment: It looks like `connect-src` is exactly what I was looking for, and that this is solved by a Content Security Policy.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

A simple one that restricts (only) scripts so they can only be loaded from the same origin as the HTML document would look like this HTTP response header:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src *; script-src 'self'
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this prevents loading files from other domains. But it doesn't prevent already loaded JavaScript from making network requests to other domains, which is the topic of my question.

Comment: @MattH - There are only files, nothing else. Loading a file and making a network request is the same thing (well, apart form local files from the hard disk)